# Discord bot - why is sqlite not loading? Filename/null error

Tags: sqlite, discord

My full code is at https://github.com/jep-dev/warn but here's the gist. I'm trying to create a bot that converts one or more reactions of :warning:/⚠️  into a single moderator notification. (The first reaction of ⚠️ by a user should notify a moderator, but further ⚠️ shouldn't spam them.)

I'm getting this error:

```
/home/john/dev/warn/node_modules/sqlite/build/Database.js:37
            throw new Error('sqlite: filename cannot be null / undefined');
                  ^

Error: sqlite: filename cannot be null / undefined
at /home/john/dev/warn/node_modules/sqlite/build/Database.js:37:23
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Database.open (/home/john/dev/warn/node_modules/sqlite/build/Database.js:33:16)
at Object.open (/home/john/dev/warn/node_modules/sqlite/build/index.js:14:14)
at Database.load (/home/john/dev/warn/database.js:6:18)
at start (/home/john/dev/warn/warn.js:77:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/john/dev/warn/warn.js:83:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)

Node.js v20.5.1
```

But the code in question *is* loading from a filename.

```
await this.sql.open("database/scores.sqlite");
```

The file is empty, but it exists. Is that the problem or am I calling it wrong? Let me know if you need to see more code here.

Edit:

```
 5          load: async function (fname) {
 6                  await this.sql.open(fname);
 7                  await this.sql.migrate();
                    ...
19          }
```

called by

```
 77         await db.load("database/scores.sqlite");
```

Comment: `await this.sql.open("database/scores.sqlite");` Are you **sure** that's the line of code that causes the error?  The error mentions a null/undefined filename, which suggests the error is actually happening elsewhere, because that line of code clearly does have a filename.

Comment: @JohnGordon Positive, going by line number as well as surrounding context. https://github.com/jep-dev/warn/blob/cf8af00ca601aa9bf3327ea009383c95e4752ed6/database.js#L6

Comment: The filename "database/scores.sqlite" assumes that "warn" is the current directory.  Is that the case?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, it's `/home/john/dev/warn/database/scores.sqlite` in full.

Comment: The filename you're using is `database/scores.sqlite`, so to get that desired full path, the actual current working directory would have to be `/home/john/dev/warn`.  Is it?

Comment: I had it written as "./database/scores.sqlite" originally, changed it in testing. By the way this is code adapted from https://github.com/SvDvorak/reacty. And yes, that's the working directory. I execute as `node warn.js` from `/home/john/dev/warn`

Comment: And frankly this is just a weak guess on my part.  The error message says the filename is null/undefined, which is not the same as a filename that _cannot not be opened_.  So I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @JohnGordon That's true but I was trying to cover all my bases - it's like a null file, so maybe there's a miscategorized error message somewhere in sqlite. Seems unlikely, but hey. I updated a few things in the code base but it's effectively the same line; now in database.js it accepts a filename as it was passed from warn.js, and warn.js uses double quotes. I'll update my question to include both sites.

Comment: It might be useful to look at `sqlite/build/Database.js` where that error is actually thrown, to see what actual condition triggers it.

Comment: Great suggestion. It's pretty explicitly just the filename being checked at that line. As in `if(filename == null || filename == undefined)`, no room for other errors I can see.

Comment: I see I'm supposed to have "resolve, reject" as the parameters to a Promise, could that be relevant? I don't have a reject callback set. (Open in sqlite is a Promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite `open` does not accept a filename as a parameter.  It accepts an object which has a `filename` element.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite

You need:

```
        await this.sql.open({filename: fname});
```